# Modifying nonexistant DOM elements in WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm displaying a webpage in a WKWebView. To hide elements like the header or sidebars, I'm applying JavaScript. The problem is I'm using one script for various pages of the same site, and page elements different for different types of pages. If I do something like this:

```
    let scriptURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myscript", ofType: "js")
    let scriptContent = String(contentsOfFile:scriptURL!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
    let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptContent!, injectionTime: .AtDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    config.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
```

…

```
document.getElementById("header").style.display = "none";
```

for a nonexistent element, it errors out and the rest of the JavaScript doesn't get applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to check to see whether or not the element is valid before proceeding. Instead of putting `if` statements everywhere, you can just define a function as so:

```
var setElementDisplayStyle = function(id, style) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  if(element) element.style.display = style;
}
```

Usage:

```
setElementDisplayStyle("header", "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to something like this

```
var header = document.getElementById("header")
if (header) {
    header.style.display = "none";
}
```